# Retrieve number of Draw Calls in OpenGL GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I know that i can get many GPU Specific Information with the function **glGetIntegerv()**. How about Number of Draw-Calls?

By the way, when a Guru could give more Info about draw-calls, would be very nice!

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use something like this:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/BuGLe/

I have not tried BuGLe, so can't say how effective it is.

Alternatively you can count the number of calls you make to e.g. glDrawElements and build up per-frame stats yourself.

Or use an OpenGL profiler.  If you are using a Mac, [there's one on OSX which will give you stats on all OpenGL calls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLProfilerUserGuide/GettedStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006475-CH20-SW1).